# I can't make my simple Selenium test work on any browser

Tags: php, google-chrome, selenium, phpunit

I have a very simple and classic installation:

- Windows 7
- WampServer with PEAR (PHP 5.3.5)
- PHPUnit and Selenium installed from PEAR
- Netbeans plugin "Selenium Module for PHP"

I'm trying to run the following test:

```
<?php
require_once 'PHPUnit/Extensions/SeleniumTestCase.php';

class WebTest extends PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase
{
    protected function setUp()
    {
        $this->setBrowser('*googlechrome');
        $this->setBrowserUrl('http://www.google.com');
    }

    public function testTitle()
    {
        $this->open('http://www.google.com');
    }
}
```

- With `*googlechrome`, I get the error : "Cannot call method 'indexOf' of undefined".
- With `*firefox`, I get no error but a blank firefox page, and nothing happens.
- With `*opera`, it's almost fine : the page "google.com" is opened but does not loaded completely (missing one element of five) and the test fails after 30 seconds
- With `*safari`, the test starts (Safari and the Selenium window are opened) but that's it...
- I don't even want to try on Internet Explorer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally understood my (stupid) error !

I just, somehow, installed a quite old version of the Selenium Server, absolutely unable to deal with recent browsers. The solution is obvious then : I updated my Selenium Server (by downloading the most recent .jar file there : http://seleniumhq.org/download/) and it all worked well !

Answer (score 0):

You could try defining the path to the browser.
For example

```
"*firefox C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe"
```

instead of just 
"`*firefox`"